# Random Numbers using Arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add 8 random numbers to my array and display them. Right now, it is only displaying one random number, and I can't figure out why.

Code:

```
var array = [ ];
window.onload = function () {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        array.push(rand);
        answer = 'Your array is this: ' + array[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `answer` in each iteration of your loop, and then writing the final value of answer to your document.

Further, you also need to generate the random number in the loop, or you'll end up with the same number every time.

Instead of assigning the new value to `answer` in the loop, append it to `answer`:

```js
var array = [ ];
var answer = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  array.push(rand);
  answer = answer + 'Your array is this: ' + array[i] + '<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = answer;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh1dnzqr/)